# Dockerize angular-cli 4 project fails while trying to run "ng build --aot --prod"

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, angular-cli

I am trying to dockerize my angular-cli projectwith the following docker file: I did followed the steps from:

https://github.com/avatsaev/angular4-docker-example

---- DOCKER FILE ------

```html
FROM nginx:1.13-alpine

ENV APP_PATH /app
ENV PATH $APP_PATH/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/:$PATH


RUN apk add --update --no-cache nodejs && mkdir $APP_PATH && rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
WORKDIR $APP_PATH

COPY . .

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

ARG NPM_TOKEN
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY package.json package.json

RUN npm install
  ng build --aot --prod \
  && rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/* \
  && mv ./dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
  && npm cache clean \
  && apk del nodejs libstdc++ libgcc libuv http-parser ca-certificates \
  && rm -rf ./*

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

It downloads the packages, runs npm install fine and it fails on "build ng build --aot --prod", 
It downloads all package successfully including typescript no idea why its failing here,
I didn't get any clue from the exception what is wrong in here:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Comment: As a total guess - have you tried installing Typescript globally before running `ng build` ?
> `npm install typescript -g`

Comment: @Steveland83 i tried but i am getting same error still no idea why aot cant find the module...

Comment: apparently found out that there was a  problem with my private registry, so i changed my authorization token in .npmrc file and it worked.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question here with details of the specific cause for anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: @Steveland83 sure thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the package in package.json was referring to private registry my mistake was instead of tagging private registry only for that package i did a global tagging in my .npmrc file which looks like

```
"registry=URl private registry"
```

which should be

```
"scope:registry=URL for private registry"
```

so it was downloading the public packages from the private registry which  didn't download some modules as expected for some reason. That is why i was getting 
`Cannot find module 'typescript' error`. 
In the same time the authorization token in my .npmrc file got corrupted because of multiple retries i am not exactly sure how butt i had to delete the file and revoke the token again and do a fresh `npm install` to make it work. Following link has information regarding the npm token and downloading private package for docker. I hope this helps in case anyone gets similar issue.

https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/ci-server-config